# Not fetching dynamic dropdown using jquery spring mvc and hibernate

Tags: java, jquery, hibernate, spring-mvc

While click on an add button i have given the jquery code to navigate next page.

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("#id-add-mer").click(function(){
        location.href="../ecom/addMer";
});
```

here is my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addMer", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String addMerchant() {
       return "merchantRegistration";
}
```

here it redirects to that page, but i have 3 dynamically fetching dropdown inside this page. i'm trying to fetch the values by adding an onload event in the body tag. here is my ajax code

```
function loadDropDown(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "ecom/loadInd",
            data: {}, 
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                count = Object.keys(data).length;
                $("#id-industry").empty();
                for(i=0;i<count;i++){
                    $("#id-industry").append('<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].type+'</option>');
                }
                loadBank();
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("1Server Exception");
            }

        });

    }
```

i'm making an ajax call to fetch 2nd dropdown at the success of 1st call. while loading this page as welcome file displays the fetched dropdowns, i'm using spring mvc and hibernate to retrieve the records. But here i'm getting the error. Can anyone tell me how can i fix this issue..Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you can mention here, what you get as error message in your code. Otherwise try to follow below steps to identify the issue.

First of all you better check whether your http request can access your server. you can use third party tools as well as built-in element viewer for that.

if there is no issue with communication with controller then check the what will return from "/loadInd". Simply you can debug or you can use alert box to inside success block.

Happy Coding....

Comment: its not entering to success function ..i'm getting alert from error function